# Trace where print is occurring?

Tags: python, printing

Given the novice that I am, I have an extremely naive question, apologies for that

I modified certain core .py files by adding `print`. Now it's printing a bunch of lines and I'm unable to trace what file I added the `print` statement. How can I find out what line / file the `print` is occurring, so that i can go back and remove it? It happens when code executes `import sklearn`.

I tried debugging and going back to certain files I had modified and searching for `print` statement, but not able to trace back.

Comment: ... why not reinstall sklearn?

Comment: tried , not working , i think its in some other module

Comment: open notepad++ select search in files and look in all files under python site packages ... I guess ...

Comment: You can use [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to watch Python executing code. See this article titled [**_Tracing python code_**](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html) for a simple example. [Here's some more sample code](https://pymotw.com/3/trace/index.html).

Comment: If you're using Python 3, where `print()` is a function, you could redefine it to raise an exception when called.

Answer (score 1):

OPTIONS:

1. Remember what you were trying to do when you went in and edited the .py files in the first place,  and that might give you a recollection of which files you changed.
2. Search the python folder and sort by date stamp.   The py files that have been recently changed are LIKELY to be the ones you edited.  Then go in and revert the edit you made
3. Flush your Python install and reinstall from scratch. (The 'Nuke the planet from orbit, it's the only way to be sure' option)

In general its a BAD idea to go in and edit the core Python files unless you REALLY know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling `sklearn` is probably the simplest and easiest option.

Otherwise you can try using [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to find the troublesome line(s).

```
python -m pdb myscript.py
```

Simply mash `s` (per-function) and `n` (line-by-line search) to taste until you find the undesirable statements.